# Inserting date into database when we insert data to database every time display inserting date in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i inserting data into database i need to insert date also but i pass a insert query in this query i inserted data but it took date column by default SQL database date format but i want to display when the user enter data to insert data base that date i want to display my tried query is:

```
string s = "insert into BatchPermissons(BatchId,SubjectId,AuditoName,AudioID,CreatedBy,CreatedDate) values(" + batchno + ", " + subjectid + " , '" + AudiotoName + "', " + AudioId + ",'" + CBY + "'," + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ")";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

but the above query inserting default date in database.i need to insert when i insert data that particular date will be store can any one help me out.

Comment: I'd like to introduce you to my little friend called "punctuation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` with `"getdate()"`. This will take the date from SQL server. Or add format to the `ToString`

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: i pass same method but in query but i am getting incorrect syntax error near 13. it will show the error near time

Comment: @user123 you got missing `'` characters around your datetime value.

Answer (score 2):

If the date input will always be the current date then you can use the sql method  [`getdate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188383.aspx) to fill the value. if it is not, you have to give the date in proper format, that means in `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"` it is simple to change the format using `.ToString()` so the query will be :

```
string s = "insert into BatchPermissons(...,CreatedDate) values(...," + getdate() + ")"; // using standard method date
```

Or

```
string s = "insert into BatchPermissons(...,CreatedDate) values(...," + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + ")"; // using formated date
```

Special note:

Can we stop opening way to [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) using `text only` queries and start writing parameterised queries? So that we can avoid the unwanted FormatingException and also give protection from injection. In this case you can use parameterised queries like the following:

```
string QuerySql = "insert into BatchPermissons(BatchId,SubjectId,AuditoName,AudioID,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)" +
"values(@batchno,@subjectid,@AudiotoName,@AudioId ,@CBY,@dtime)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = QuerySql;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@batchno", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = batchno;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@subjectid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = subjectid;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AudiotoName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AudiotoName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AudioId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = AudioId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CBY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CBY;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

if you are using the `getdate()` method then you can avoid the last Parameter from adding value, it will be like the following:

```
"values(@batchno,@subjectid,@AudiotoName,@AudioId ,@CBY,getdate())"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Database column type is `datetime` then try to insert `datetime` directly like this-

```
string s = "insert into BatchPermissons(BatchId,SubjectId,AuditoName,AudioID,CreatedBy,CreatedDate) values(" + batchno + ", " + subjectid + " , '" + AudiotoName + "', " + AudioId + ",'" + CBY + "'," + DateTime.Today + ")";
```